# After finding all the links and texts using find_all in Beautiful Soup how do grab the one that you need

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

result = requests.get("https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/")
c = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c,'lxml')
patch_name = soup.find_all(["a", "p"])
u = soup.get_text()
print(u)
```

How do I get the text I need for I can store it in a variable for later usage.

Comment: Which text you need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will return a list of `a` and `p` tag:

```
patch_name = soup.find_all(["a", "p"])
```

you can get all the text of the list :

```
[tag.get_text() for tag in patch_name]
```

Comment: What if I only want one sentence.

Comment: @nomekop this will return a list, you can index it and get the element out.